# Data Correlation for Predictive Basketball Model

Tags: correlation, predictive-models, computational-statistics

**Background Information: (scroll for question)**

Attempting to find correlation between the average number of fouls committed by each basketball team in a game and the referees calling the game. Such a relationship would provide a predictive model for the total expected number of fouls predicted in any match. With the extraordinarily human dependent element of this data and the relative unpredictability of a basketball game, such a correlation would be weak at best, but interesting nonetheless.

---

My initial strategy was to consider what portion of the actual outcome came from the expectations of the teams and refs respectively, leading to the following relationship:

$$aX + bY = c \\
a = sum \ average  \ commited \ fouls \ by \ both \ teams \\
b = average \ num \ fouls \ called \ by \ specific \ refs \\
c = actual \ outcome = total \ num \ fouls$$

I assumed $X$ & $Y$ would be simple probabilities summing to 1 to complete a total outcome. However I quickly realized this wasn't a possibility as any outcome $c$ greater than $a$ or $b$ would be invalid and thus disregarded in the predictive model, destroying accuracy in the process.

---

I have compiled data from 20 games in the google doc below. As expected for such a small sample size the data is anything but conclusive. That being said, data is available for 1000s of samples once a statistical model is selected. I've included a graph of the data below for convenience.

[image: sample data]

Sample Data: http://goo.gl/SrlRnQ [google doc]

---

**Question & Inquiry:**

Why I've come to Cross Validated is to seek out an ideal statistical method for determine such a correlation in this data. It seems a liner regression may be the route to go although I'm not sure how to proceed.

The available data is on the order of 1000s of sets, not just the 20 I have provided. Given this data, what is the best way to determine a consistent, or at least average, prediction of the contributions of both the teams and the refs in the outcome. I.e. what portion, on average, of the outcome can be directly attributed to each party across 1000s of samples.

My initial model led me to believe an average, universal scaler could be calculated for both a and b given above to predict the outcome. As this would be a mere average, it wouldn't be terribly accurate, but I'm curious to see just that the correlation is.

Comment: Where did you get the data????